# How to make a video play in powerpoint

Tags: video-streaming, powerpoint, jwplayer

I need the videos that are available in my site to be played with powerpoint 2007 as the youtube videos play.

My site is eduvisiontest.info i have many videos in this site.I am using JW Player in my site.Now my requirement is to play these videos inside the powerpoint.

How can i achieve it?Any ideas?

Comment: This should be asked at superuser.com instead as it's not programming related.

Answer (score 1):

Look into Shyam Pillai's LiveWeb add-in.  It enables you to embed a web browser into your PPT presentations and set the URL to point at videos or whatever else the browser could play.

http://skp.mvps.org

Answer (score 0):

You can insert video into PowerPoint, but if you want to upload the PowerPoint onto the web, you need to convert the PowerPoint to video format with a [PowerPoint to video converter](http://www.ppt-utilities.com/powerpoint-to-video.html).

Answer (score 0):

Can you play your videos with the Windows media player control that comes with Windows? With some VBA Programming it can be used to play videos from files and URLs.

The Windows Media player OCX control knows to play lots of different multimedia formats, especially the new version that's included with Windows 7.

This is only feasible, if you don't have to redistribute your multimedia-embedded PPT files, and/or  if you have absolute control over the machine where the PPTs are supposed to be viewed.

The Macro security subsystem is a pain to deal with. Just sayin'.